# zwCreateProcess to stop taskmanager

Tags: c#, taskmanager

I'm trying to stop taskmanager opening in C#. I have not been successful in disabling ctrl+alt+delete so I was looking into stopping taskmanager starting up itself.

Edit : I actually can disable taskmanager completely however because it's doing it in the registry I'm assuming I'm going to have to do it once the program is installed as I don't want to have to start the program as admin everytime the computer starts, unless that is possible without the user having to authenticate?

I've been suggested to use zwCreateProcess but theres not much out there about it in regards how to diasble taskmanager starting. Has anyone here had experience with this sort of thing and would know how to use zwCreateProcess to programatically stop taskmanager starting?

[image]

Comment: I've had no luck using methods that change the registry. I get issues such as these. http://i.imgur.com/dZFvQJv.png - I can't afford starting the application in administrator mode as my app will be starting with windows each time via a scheduled task.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Trying to disable fundamental features of the broader OS environment using undocumented functions is generally not a good way to develop software.

Comment: Making a basic lock screen system for windows 7 which allows you to add times you want the computer being restricted. I've been struggling with disabling the computer so it can't be used. I also don't want my lockscreen form to be disabled so I can't allow taskmanager to be disabled. I've now managed to disable taskmanager however it is through the registry and I'm not sure how I would go about introducing that to my program. There are 2 likely scenarios both in which this could work. 1. It is possible for scheduler to start my app as admin without the user logging in. 2. Perma disable tskmgr.

Comment: is this something a user would install in order to, for example, keep themselves on task, or is it something that admins would install to keep users from using the computer too long? In either case, it'd be better to simply use group policy to restrict what users can do. The path you are taking is going to lead to heartburn, especially if Windows is updated and your hack no longer works.

Comment: I'm really inexperienced with this sort of thing. It would definetly be the latter, admins install to keep users from using the computer too long. I mean, lets say if for the given user I want to leave the task manager permanently disabled, is that possible ? I guess I just make the installer require admin rights to run allowing it to do the task manager disable for the user ? @siride

Comment: I don't know the details either, but I'm pretty sure it's the way to go. Take a look at this, for example: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/35dd3cd6-cc67-476f-82e2-058293e6f657/how-do-i-disable-task-manager-for-users-only

Comment: @siride I've decided to do the registry change to disable task manager for the user during the installation process. Limit the users to use taskmanager, seems okay in my particular scenario. I do however feel that someone should make a little tutorial of some sort on how to create this effect using the zwCreateProcess method.

Comment: I think your method is the same, albeit using a less documented method. zwCreateProcess will not let you hide task manager. What you've probably read about is hiding processes from task manager. Either way, don't bother and I hope nobody else does either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a work around I did not use global keyboard hooks as it is near enough impossible to prevent ctrl+alt+delete and for good reasons too. Instead for the particular user I wanted not to be able to start task manager I disabled task manager via the registry during installation.

I hope this offers a suitable solution to anyone who was trying to do the same.